# Meteor AngularJS templates (unit testing)

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, meteor, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

How to test angular directives with Meteor? In a normal app, I have karma.conf.js with html2js preprocessor, but in meteor it's different (packages).

Now i have something like this: https://github.com/Nitrooos/Forum-Steganum/tree/templates, but i got `Unexpected GET "client/posts/postsList/postsList.directive.html"` error.

I tried with this package https://atmospherejs.com/sanjo/angular-templating, but I can't find any example how to configure it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved it. Now I'm making unit tests via gulp, server tests are via velocity.

An example you can find in this repo: https://github.com/SuperGrupa/Forum-Steganum

Hope it will help.